# I am learning javascript and i'm stuck with the concept of function returning function

Tags: nested-function

please help me with below code.I did not understand the functioning of **return function(object1,object2)**.How does the return function in create comparison function() get its parameters.?

```js
var data = [{ name: "Zachary", age: 28}, {name: "Nicholas", age: 29}];

function createComparisonFunction( propertyName) 
{
   return function( object1, object2)
   { 
     var value1 = object1[ propertyName]; 
     var value2 = object2[ propertyName]; 
     if (value1 < value2)
     { 
       return -1; 
     } 
     else if (value1 > value2)
     { 
       return 1; 
     }
     else 
     { 
       return 0; 
     } 
   }; 
}
data.sort( createComparisonFunction(" name")); 
alert( data[ 0]. name); // Nicholas 
data.sort( createComparisonFunction(" age"));
alert( data[ 0]. name); // Zachary
```

Comment: "help you" *how* exactly?  What is the problem that you're encountering?

Comment: I think he's asking what that line of code does.  I'm interested to know the answer as well.

Comment: I hope now David understands how he can help exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume that `sort` function is similar to the below code.

```
function sort( comparefunction )
{
  ...
  if ( comparefunction(obj1, obj2 ){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Now because `comaprefunction` itself is something like `createComparisonFunction("name")` you will have something like this in the end:
`createComparisonFunction("name")(obj1, obj2)` which `name` is the input for `createComparisonFunction` and `obj1, obj2` are the inputs for the nameless function.

Answer (score 0):

When the sort() method compares two values, it sends the values to the compare function, and sorts the values according to the returned (negative, zero, positive) value.